# How frequent is the euro?

Tags: eur-euro

I want to know how many 1 euro coins are there on the world. Actually, I want to know how many 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1, 2 coins and 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 banknotes are there on the world. I need to know how frequent is 0.01, 0.02, 0.05 ... euro in comparison with 1 euro.

I have no real reason for this question because I am asking this out just in curiosity.

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/banknotes+coins/circulation/html/index.en.html

Comment: I've voted to close as off-topic since any data provided would be stale, so essentially OP is asking for a service that provides the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_coins), as of July 2019 there are 133,437,760,625 (little over 133 billion) Euro coins in circulation. This is broken up as such:

[image]

This data is pulled from the European Central Bank, [found here](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/banknotes+coins/circulation/html/index.en.html).